# What is exact use of Android Service?

Tags: android

What is the cons of using Thread instead of using Android Service in an App for long running task. What will happen if I don't use Android Service for long running task?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? A thread and a service are 2 completely different things

Comment: Service can provide you two things. Stability for long running operations, flexibility to use it with activity and UI. For exemple if you use a foreground service android won't be able to kill it as normal service (good for streaming audio for example)... etc Threads are the most basing multitasking method. It is the most powerfull but it takes more work to have a thread safe app without conflicts. You would better use "Volley" which is based on Threads. Asynctask is the easy to use threading BUT have some buggy part to it http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What will happen if I don't use Android Service for long running task?

**You might get lucky and your code finishes. Then again, you might not get lucky, and your code gets killed at a random point in time.**

Aside from the textbook descriptions of what an Android `Service` is and what a `Thread` is, the main difference between the two which is directly relevant to your question is how the OS threats them.

A **thread** is a way to **execute code in the background**, while a **service** is a way to **make Android aware** you are executing code in the background.

As far as the underlying Linux kernel is concerned, it knows only about threads, and cares about them only with regards to thread switching and prioritization. Whether there is a service has no impact on this.

However, as far as the Android device memory management and task prioritization goes, Android does not know or care about threads in your process. It only knows about services, and interacts with them on the main app process thread only.

Thus, for as long as you have a thread alive, the kernel will happily try to keep the process alive and allocate CPU time for that thread execution.

However, unless you have an activity, service, content provider, or a broadcast receiver alive, the Android memory manager might decide to **kill your process** to reclaim its resources for another higher priority process, no matter what threads might be working at this point.

Therefore, while you could go away with running stuff on a separate thread if the user is interacting with your activity, if you want to make sure the background task finishes successfully and is not interrupted at a random point, you need to wrap it in a service (preferably one that is bound by an activity, or is elevated to UI priority by showing a notification).

Note that having a service does not guarantee you that its code will be running in the background. Android will call the lifecycle methods (onStartCommand/onBind/onCreate/OnDestroy) on the main thread of the application process. Your code will have to start a thread to ensure true background execution.

Answer (score 3):

**Service:**

A service is a component which `runs in the background, without direct interaction with the user`. As the service has no user interface it is `not bound to the lifecycle of an activity`.

`Services are used for repetitive and potential long running operations`, like Internet downloads, checking for new data, data processing, updating content providers and the like.

It is possible to assign services the same priority as foreground activities. In this case it is required to have a visible notification active for the related service. It is frequently used for services which play videos or music.

**Threads:**

They are simple runnable threads. You can execute non UI stuff with these threads but you can't perform UI tasks in them (as UI is not thread safe). For dealing with UI in these threads, you will have to use `Handlers`, which is quite cumbersome for beginners to get a grip and understanding of them.

So depending on your needs and app you can choose the one best suits you.

Answer (score 1):

- A [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is an application component that can perform
  long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user
  interface. Another application component can start a service and it
  will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to
  another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service
  to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication
  (IPC). For example, a service might handle network transactions, play
  music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all
  from the background.
- On other hand, [Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) are the cornerstone of any multitasking
  operating system and can be thought of as mini-processes running
  within a main process, the purpose of which is to enable at least the
  appearance of parallel execution paths within applications.

They are to be used as per requirement and we cannot actually point out pros and cons of either of them as both of them are essential in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Services are highly recommended and used in Android to do both foreground and background tasks. Instead of going into the definitions I would highly recommend you to look into IntentService class specifically in Android. Available from API Level 3 this class does most of the worker thread heavy lifting for your background task. This class handles asynchronous requests expressed as Intents. Clients send request using startService(Intent) calls. The service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work. Coolest thing you can use this along with an AlarmManager implementation to do say what you want to do every 10-15 mins and still not worry about threads and handler explicit implementation as you would have to if you use Service class.

Here is a short bit of code on how to implement it.

```
 public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

 public UpdateService() {           
            //constructor
        }

            @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
                //Called by the system when the service is first created.
        }

          public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                super.onStart(intent, startId);
                return(START_REDELIVER_INTENT); //Intent Relidelivery
                            //You should not override this method for your 
                            IntentService and remember onStart() for IntentService is 
                            deprecated.

            }

            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
             //do your main background tasks here forget about threading doing anything 
               in here Android will do the heavylifting as required  
            }

                @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                    //finalize your objects GC etc here
                    //Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer          
                      used and is being removed.
            }
```

}

Services are best implementations for long running tasks that you don't need user input or ui updates right away. If you absolutely don't need to don't use threads and handlers since you might come across a lot of concurrency / deadlock etc issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing will happen, I ran an algorithm in a async task about 90 hours. Worked fine.

Async Task: seperate a "heavy" task from the UI, for example a download
Service: seperate a task from the App, for example an alarm clock